# What video API works well with Ionic framework for video recording and playback?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, vimeo

I have an Ionic web app that uses Vimeo, but I need to replace Vimeo with something else because it is banned in select countries in Asia. I was considering Amazon AWS. What options do I have that is not banned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own video streaming using CloudFront. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialStreamingJWPlayer.html for an example implementation using JWPlayer as the client player.